# Get Multiple NICs Speed 10/100/1000

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have the following batch file, however, it freaks out if you have more than one NIC enabled and spits out output of Speed for the first NIC it reports, but for any more, it reports

```
Speed = Missing Operand
```

How can I fix this?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic nic where NetEnabled^=true get speed /value ^| find /i "speed"') do set /a speed=%%a
set /a speed=((%speed%/1024)/1024)
echo Speed in megabytes: %speed% Mbps
pause
```

In addition, why doesn't it work in batch file execution without the `'^'` before the `'='` and `'|'`

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic nic where NetEnabled^=true get speed /value ^| find /i "speed"') do set "speed=%%a"
set /a speed=speed/1048576 2>nul
if %speed% neq 0 (echo Speed in megabytes: %speed% Mbps) else echo No speed available.
```

You need to escape `=` and `|` in the  for-loop, no matter if batch or cmd window. It's because it's in the  for-loop.

Comment: This still doesn't give the correct output if you have multiple NICs. Come to think how would it even be possible? Surely you would need to actually print out each NIC speed within a loop otherwise you would keep overwriting the variable speed?